# How to make result like this image?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

The result that i want look like

[image]

I need help ..

How to implement the logic that lists numbers in a table in the range of 00 - 99 like this using react-native or javascript?

Comment: a for loop is a good place to start

Comment: need help sir @JaromandaX

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @WhiteDeveloper - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using FlatList check below code for same.

[Working example](https://snack.expo.dev/v80rl1QkE)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
const items = Array.from({length: 100}, (x, i) => i);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={10}
        data={items}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.box}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
  },
  box: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 30
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double For-loop. each loop will be length of 10(0 to  9).

```
for(let i=0; i< 10; i++){
    for(let j=0; j < 10; j++){
       console.log(i,j,"i + j")
    }
}
```